# Measuring the similarity of arrays with differing lengths

Tags: machine-learning

I have two 2-D arrays:

```
a: [(1,2), (1,3) (2,3), (4,5), ...... (100,101), (101,102)]

b: [(2,2), (2,1) (3,2), (4,3), ...... (100,99), (101,101)]
```

Assume length of a: **101**
Assume length of b: **101**

and one array:

```
c: [(4,4), (4,5), (7,7) ... (22,24)]
```

Assume length of c: **21**

I would like to find a way to know if array c is *more* similar to a or b.

===========

What I have tried so far is quite simple, but the results are not that perfect:

1. Step 1: calculate the [DTW distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) of c and a, using window size of length of array c (since the array c is smaller) you will get an array of DTW distance, and get the average value of it. i.e. 0.212
2. Step 2: do the same thing on c and b, get the average value. i.e. 0.32
3. Step 3: as the calculation above to know, c is more similar to a, since the average dtw distance is smaller.

BUT (there is always a but :| ), the results is not perfect, mistake happened.

===========

**Append to my original question:**

A better way of doing this? Be care the array of c is not fixed.

Many thanks guys.

Comment: "the results is not perfect" <- what does this mean? What was the mistake? What would be a perfect result?

Comment: there is too much noise on the array c. Sometimes a vs c == 0.5 and b vs c == 0.5, too...

Answer (score 0):

DTW is a good measurement for distances, but after taking it, you're doing just an average, which is obviously not a good measurement for distances since it does not take into account the deviation, for example. It is not clear how do you end with an array after taking the distances. Your array seems to be a made of vectors, so it's just a common array, but instead of having A and B as scalars in |A - B|, you should take them as vectors.

Also you said that array a is smaller than c, but on the example, array a is said to have a length of 101, and array c is said to have an array length of 21.

I also recommend for further research that you take a look at FastDTW, which is an amortized linear in time and space algorithm for DTW:
https://code.google.com/p/fastdtw/

And HMM:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model